# Is there an app/extension to have UTC appear in the Sierra Finder (10.12.2) menu?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, timezone

Is there an app/extension to have UTC appear in the Sierra Finder (10.12.2) menu ?

I bought "UTC Bar" version 1.31 from the Apple Store, but clicking on "Open" doesn't appear anywhere in the "Date & Time" preferences nor in the Finder Menu - No indication it was installed anywhere.

I prefer toggling UTC to be displayed in the menu rather than bring up the Dashboard each time.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply install [BitBar](https://getbitbar.com/) and an additional [plugin related to time](https://getbitbar.com/plugins/Time) (probably WorldClock [direct download](https://getbitbar.com/plugins/Time/worldclock.1s.sh)) which displays current UTC time in the menu bar, with various timezones in the drop-down menu:

[image]

All apps/plugins are free.